Inconsistency with Tequila API: Retrieving IATA Codes for Flights from london
image of the spread sheet I'm developing a program that retrieves IATA codes for flights based on user-defined locations and destinations. I'm utilizing the Tequila API for both GET and POST requests. However, I encountered an inconsistency: when I use a GET request, Tokyo's IATA code is returned as "TK", but when I use a PUT request, it expects the IATA code for Tokyo to be "TYO". Consequently, errors arise when dealing with some other cities for most of the cities it's working as expected .Can anyone provide guidance on how to address this?
main.py:-
from notification_manager import NotificationManager
from data_manager import DataManager
from flight_search import FlightSearch
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

#This file will need to use the DataManager,FlightSearch, FlightData, NotificationManager classes to achieve the program requirements
flight_search=FlightSearch()
notificationmanager=NotificationManager()
data_manager=DataManager()

ORIGIN_CITY_IATA="LON"

sheet_data=data_manager.get_destination_data()
if sheet_data[0]["iataCode"]=="":
    for row in sheet_data:
        row["iataCode"]=flight_search.get_destination_code(row["city"])
    data_manager.destination_data=sheet_data
    data_manager.update_destination_codes()

tomorrow=datetime.now()+timedelta(days=1)
six_month_from_today=datetime.now()+timedelta(days=(6*30))

for destination in sheet_data:
    flight=flight_search.check_flights(
        ORIGIN_CITY_IATA,
        destination["iataCode"],
        from_time=tomorrow,
        to_time=six_month_from_today
    )

flight_data.py:-
class FlightData:
    #This class is responsible for structuring the flight data.
    def __init__(self,price,origin_city,origin_airport,destination_city,destination_airport,out_date,return_date):
        self.price=price
        self.origin_city=origin_city
        self.origin_airport=origin_airport
        self.destination_city=destination_city
        self.destination_airport=destination_airport
        self.out_date=out_date
        self.return_date=return_date

data_manager.py:-
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import requests
import os

# Load environment variables from .env file
load_dotenv()

class DataManager:
    #This class is responsible for talking to the Google Sheet.
    def __init__(self):
        self.shetty_endpoint=os.environ.get("SHETTY_ENDPOINT")
        self.destination_data={}
    def get_destination_data(self):
        sheet_response=requests.get(url=self.shetty_endpoint)
        sheet_data=sheet_response.json()
        self.destination_data=sheet_data["prices"]
        return self.destination_data
    def update_destination_codes(self):
        for city in self.destination_data:
            new_data={
                "price":{
                    "iataCode":city["iataCode"]
                }
            }
            sheet_response=requests.put(url=f"{self.shetty_endpoint}/{city["id"]}",json=new_data)
            print(sheet_response.text)

flight_search.py:-
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from flight_data import FlightData
import datetime
import requests
import os

# Load environment variables from .env file
load_dotenv()
class FlightSearch:
    #This class is responsible for talking to the Flight Search API.
    def __init__(self):
        self.tequila_api_key=os.environ.get("TEQUILA_API_KEY")
        self.tequila_endpoint=os.environ.get("TEQUILA_ENDPOINT")
    def get_destination_code(self,city_name:str):
        params = {
            "term":city_name,
        }
        headers = {
            "accept": "application/json",
            "apikey": self.tequila_api_key
        }
        response=requests.get(url=f"{self.tequila_endpoint}/locations/query",params=params,headers=headers)
        code=response.json()["locations"][0]["code"]
        return code
    def check_flights(self,origin_city_code,destination_city_code,from_time,to_time):
        headers={
            "apikey":self.tequila_api_key
        }
        query={
            "fly_from":origin_city_code,
            "fly_to":destination_city_code,
            "date_from":from_time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"),
            "date_to":to_time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"),
            "nights_in_dst_from":7,
            "nights_in_dst_to":28,
            "one_for_city":1,
            "max_stopovers":0,
            "curr":"GBP"
        }

        response=requests.get(url=f"{self.tequila_endpoint}/v2/search",headers=headers,params=query)

        try:
            # print(response.json())
            data=response.json()["data"][0]
        except IndexError:
            print(f"No flights found for {destination_city_code}.")
            return None
        
        data_route=data["route"][0]
        flight_data=FlightData(
            price=data["price"],
            origin_city=data_route["cityFrom"],
            origin_airport=data_route["flyFrom"],
            destination_city=data_route["cityTo"],
            destination_airport=data_route["flyTo"],
            out_date=data_route["local_departure"].split("T")[0],
            return_date=data["route"][1]["local_departure"].split("T")[0]
        )
        print(f"{flight_data.destination_city}: \u00A3{flight_data.price}")
        return flight_data

